# retry after MongooseServerSelectionError connection timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want my nodejs application to retry after the inital connecton to mongoose fails. I connect to two separate databases in my application. Below is the code snippet for your reference.

```
function makeNewConnection(uri) {

    const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 180000
    });

    db.on('error', async function (error) {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connection ${this.name} ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        db.close().catch(() => console.log(`MongoDB :: failed to close connection ${this.name}`));
    });

    db.on('connected', function () {
        mongoose.set('debug', false);
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connected ${this.name}`);
    });

    db.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: disconnected ${this.name}`);
    });
    return db;
}

const localDBconnection = makeNewConnection(localDB);
const serverDBConnection = makeNewConnection(serverDB);
```

localDB and serverDB are my two connection uri's.
In case i retry with a timeout then it does not find the model instance. can someone suggest a clean way to do it.

Comment: when are you going to use localDB and when are you going to use serverDB ?

Comment: localDB and serverDB are two seperate connection uri's

Comment: do you want to use local when in development and server in production ??? if yes you can use environment variables to store the mongo uri and just replace it in production

Comment: No jack. The requirement is to connect to two separate databases. I guess you are diverting from the main issue here.